# get script to work on remote servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want the below code to work on multiple computers - any idea how to do this? I have the below but it fails as I do not currently call in the servers in question I think.

Thanks,

CODE:

```
Write-Host "Script to check Storage Write, Read and Delete Times"
Write-Host "`n"

$computer = Get-Content -path d:\temp\servers.txt
$path = "f:\temp\test.txt"

Foreach ($storage in $computer)
{

$date = Get-Date
Write-Host "Script being run on $date"

$write = Measure-Command { new-item -Path $path -ItemType File -Force } | select TotalMilliseconds 

Write-Host "Writing file on $storage took $write"

$read = Measure-Command { Get-Content -Path $path } | select TotalMilliseconds 

Write-Host "Reading file on $storage took $read"

$delete = Measure-Command {Remove-Item -Path $path -Force } | select TotalMilliseconds 

Write-Host "Deleting file on $storage took $delete"
Write-Host "`n"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to step back for a second an rethink the approach. You are issuing the filesystem commands every time to f:\temp, which is on your local system.

There are two ways to make remote computers perform filesystem tasks. The easiest way is to use UNC paths. That is, `\\server\share` format. Assuming you have local admin access:

```
Foreach ($storage in $computer) {
$uncpath = $("\\{0}\f`$\temp\text.txt" -f $storage)
$write = Measure-Command { new-item -Path $uncpath -ItemType #...
# rest of code uses $uncpath for access
}
```

Mind you, using UNC path puts some stess on LAN, so this type of testing might or might not be accurate enough.

The second way would be using Powershell remoting to connect on remote systems and issuing the commands there. Take a look at [New-PSSession](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849717.aspx), [Enter-PSSession](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx) and [Exit-PSSession](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849743.aspx) cmdlets.

Comment: yes! your right - the step back always works wonders. The UNC path was the thing I was missing; only am checking a couple of servers so the corporate 100GB line should cope :-)  Thanks for this and the understanding..(not done powershell remoting before - might take a look at it).